I can't set a height of 100% on the outlet components in my layout
I am developing an application with React, React-router, Material UI and Redux-Toolkit. I'm having trouble styling the height of the components that  renders. I clarify that I am a beginner with CSS and much more with material, but I have investigated and I still have not found a solution. This is my router:
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
// import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom"
import Root from './routes/root';
import ErrorPage from './errorPage';
import Applications from './routes/applications';
import Stats from './routes/stats';
import Sign from './routes/signContainer';
import SignInForm from './components/signInForm';
import SignUpForm from './components/signUpForm';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './redux/store'
import LandingPage from './routes/landingPage';
import PublicationsContainer from './routes/publicationsContainer';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <LandingPage/>,
    errorElement:<ErrorPage/>,
  },
  {
    path:"/signup",
    element:<Sign component={<SignUpForm/>} />
  },
  {
    path:'/signin',
    element:<Sign component={<SignInForm/>} />
  },
  {
    path:"/home",
    element:<Root/>,
    children:[
      {
        path: "postulaciones",
        element: <Applications/>,
      },
      {
        path: "publicaciones",
        element: <PublicationsContainer/>,
      },
      {
        path: "estadisticas",
        element: <Stats/>,
      }
    ]
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

this is my layout:
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Box, CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import NavBar from "../components/navBar";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserInfo } from "../redux/actions/userActions";


export default function Root() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  const getinfo = async (id)=> {
    await dispatch(getUserInfo(id)).unwrap()
  } 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId')
      getinfo(userId)
    }
    if (window.location.pathname === '/home') {
      navigate("/home/postulaciones");
    }
  }, [navigate]);
  
  return (
    <Box minHeight="100vh" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
      <CssBaseline />
      <NavBar />
      <Box component="main" flexGrow={1} id="content" bgcolor="red" >
        <Outlet />
      </Box>
      <Footer />
    </Box>
  );
}


What I want to achieve is that the components rendered by the  have a height of 100% between the navbar and the footer.
I put a bgcolor in red to be able to appreciate the height of the component, which in this case is occupying 100% between the navbar and the footer, but the problem is with the outlet components. I leave an example of a component that renders the outlet:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserApplications } from "../redux/actions/applicationsActions";
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  CircularProgress,
  Box,
  Button,
  Grid,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Add as AddIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";
import ApplicationItem from "../components/applicationItem";
import Filters from "../components/filter";
import PaginationComp from "../components/paginationComp";

export default function Applications() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const id = localStorage.getItem('userId')
  const { error, loading, userApplications } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.applications
  );
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const itemsPerPage = 8;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userApplications) {
      dispatch(getUserApplications(id));
    }  
  }, []);

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
    };
    
  const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const visibleApplications = userApplications?.slice(startIndex, startIndex + itemsPerPage);
  
  return (
    <>
    <Box bgcolor="blue" padding={2} height="100%">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2} marginBottom={2}>
          <Grid item xs={20} sm={8}>
            <Typography
              variant="h4"
              style={{ fontFamily: "Outfit, sans-serif", color: "#333333" }}
            >
              Mis Postulaciones
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={201} sm={4}>
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                startIcon={<AddIcon />}
              >
                Agregar
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Filters/>
        <Box sx={{ height: "100", width: '100%' }}>
          {loading && <CircularProgress />}
        </Box>
        {error && (
          <Typography variant="body1" color="error">
            {error.message}
          </Typography>
        )}
        {visibleApplications &&
          visibleApplications.map((application) => (
            <ApplicationItem
              key={application._id}
              application={application}
            />
          ))}
          {visibleApplications &&
            <PaginationComp
            totalItems={userApplications?.length || 0}
            itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
          />
          }
          {
            !userApplications?.length &&
            <Box height="100%" display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
              <Typography variant="h5" color="primart" fontFamily="Outfit, sansserif">
                Todavia no tienes postulaciones
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          }
        
      </Container>
    </Box>
    </>
  );
}


In this component, which would be one of those that renders the outlet, I added a blue bg to be able to see the height of the component, the problem is that even though I set the height to 100%, it does not occupy all the space between the footer and the navbar. I can still see the red bgcolor of the box component in Root.jsx. What could be the problem?
Try to set the height to 100% of the applications.jsx component, as you understand the parent component, which would be:
<Box component="main" flexGrow={1} id="content" bgcolor="red" >
   <Outlet />
</Box>

It occupies the entire height between the footer and the navbar, but I am not being able to achieve what I expected and that is that the component that renders output the minimum height should be the height between the navbar and the footer.
Also, if you have any feedback to give me extra, I will be delighted to receive it.

I haven't tried your example, but the answer also might depend on what <Outlet /> resolves at, speaking about the display type.
Inline elements like span might behave differently than block elements like div etc.
It should work e.g. when you make <Box> itself a flex container, because then  will become a flex child.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
